# Cannot connect to MySQL on Google Cloud Run due to unknown socket error

Tags: mysql, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running a .NET 6 service on Cloud Run and trying to connect using the built in socket. My instance name is `project-id:region:instance-name` and the code for building my connection is as follows...

```
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    SslMode = IsCloud ? MySqlSslMode.None : MySqlSslMode.Required,
    Server = IsCloud ? $"/cloudsql/{Endpoint}" : Endpoint,
    UserID = User,
    Password = Password,
    Database = Schema,
    Pooling = true
};

switch (IsCloud)
{
    case true: builder.ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.UnixSocket; break;
    case false: builder.Port = Convert.ToUInt32(Port); break;
}

_connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
        
return _connectionString;
```

I also added the cloud SQL connection to the Cloud Run revision configuration. But every time I run it and the container has to hit the database, I get an `unknown socket error` and nothing to go on. My code is basically the same as [the code recommended by Google](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run#public-ip-default_1), but I'm obviously doing something wrong setting up my socket because when I use a public IP, everything works without a problem.

Unfortunately, I have no idea what I could be doing wrong and would appreciate any advice. The `IsCloud` switch is there so the code can also be ran on localhost, which requires encryption and a port.

Comment: Edit your question and include the deploy command.

Comment: I'm just deploying this in the console. Like I said, public IP works perfectly well, it's only the socket that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Use the CLI to deploy. That will provide you with better control and improved messages. Also, review the service logs.

Comment: The only thing in the logs is `unknown socket error` and the stack trace of the MySQL connector. I tried to update the connections using `gcloud run services update [service-name] --add-cloudsql-instances=[project-id:region:instance-name]` and while this deployed successfully, using `/cloudsql/project-id:region:instance-name` as the server resulted in that error and nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried this link on [debugging connection issues](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/debugging-connectivity)?

Comment: Hi @gfish3000, can you share an update on this problem? We're facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the same setup, and it actually turned out to be a mySQL permission issue. When I downgraded the EntityFrameWorkCore MySQL  packages to earlier versions, I actually got an unauthorized error from mySQL, but in the new EntityFrameWorkCore connectors it just gave an unknown socket error.

Lastest on .net 6

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFE): Unknown socket error
```

Downgraded packages

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'xxxxxx' to database 'xxxx'
```

I fixed the permisson and it works fine. Locally it worked fine as I was testing with a different user.